# Как импортировать проект?

Tags: android

Скачал с гита [проект](https://github.com/ozodrukh/RippleDrawable) , открыл его в студии и вот такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно ее починить?

Comment: Самый простой способ это удалить maven зависимости

Comment: @AdamLuisSean Вы имеете ввиду ту одну строчку из градл файла? Я удалил... Но ничего не поменялось